# how to launch SQL Management Studio with SA auth mode instead of Windows Auth

Tags: sql, default-settings, sql-management-studio

When ever I launch SQL Management Studio 2014, its connect window opens up with Windows Authentication by default. How do I make it so it should show SA authentication by default?

Answer (score 0):

Add the server(s) you wish to connect to as Registered Servers in SSMS (MSDN page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190631.aspx)), then you can specify the authentication so you do not have to change it from Windows to SQL authentication each time you connect.